# What is the definition of a vector field generating a Lie group of symmetries which is not necesserally a 1-parameter group?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lie-groups, lie-algebras, integrable-systems

I was doing a question which got reduced to

> Say we have$$
> \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial y}=F(u)
> $$
> for some $F(u)$ . Show that the transformation
> $$
> (x, y) \longrightarrow\left(c x, c^{-1} y\right), \quad c \in \mathbb{R} \backslash\{0\}
> $$
> forms a symmetry group of the PDE and find the vector field generating this group.

Showing that it is a group of symmetries was easy enough. However, I am not sure what the vector field generating this group is. I have the following definitions

---

> **Defn** (**Generating Vector field with respect to a flow**) We say that a vector field $\boldsymbol{V}: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is the generating vector field with respect to a flow $g^{\varepsilon}$ if
> $$
> \boldsymbol{V}(\boldsymbol{x})=\left.\frac{d}{d \varepsilon} g^{\varepsilon} \boldsymbol{x}\right|_{\varepsilon=0} .
> $$

The motivation for this definition is that this is the leading order term in the Taylor expansion of the flow map:
$$
g^{\varepsilon} \boldsymbol{x}=\boldsymbol{x}+\varepsilon \boldsymbol{V}(\boldsymbol{x})+o(\varepsilon) .
$$

This flow map is an example of a

> **Defn** (**One-parameter group of transformations**) A smooth $\operatorname{map} g^{\varepsilon}: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is called a one-parameter group of transformations (1.p.g.t) if
> $$
> g^0=\mathrm{id}, \quad g^{\varepsilon_1} g^{\varepsilon_2}=g^{\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2} .
> $$

---

What we have here is not a one parameter group of transformations because we do not have either of the equalities.

Regardless, I tried to press on with the definition of a generating vector field which got me

$$
V(x,y)=(x,-y).
$$

This doesn't seem to be quite right as this also corresponds to the lie point symmetry
$$
g^{\varepsilon}:(x, y, u) \mapsto\left(e^{\varepsilon} x, e^{-\varepsilon} y, u\right).
$$

**Question:** What is the definition of a vector field generating a group of symmetries in the context of this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in what you wrote. The generating vector field is
$$
V(x, y)=(x, -y),
$$
and the 1-parameter group is
$$
g^t(x, y, u)=(e^t x, e^{-t}y, u).
$$

If you are interested in directly verifying this, all you need to do is to solve the system of ODEs
$$\begin{cases}
x'(t)=V_1((x(t), y(t)))=x(t),\\
y'(t)=V_2((x(t), y(t)))=-y(t),\\
x(0)=x,\ y(0)=y,
\end{cases}
$$
where $V_1$ and $V_2$ are the components of $V$.

Here is a field plot of the vector field.
[image: Field plot1]

The flow lines are branches of the hyperbolas $xy=a$ for various constants $a$. This matches with your transformation
$$
(x, y)\to (cx, c^{-1}y),\quad c\in {\mathbb R}\backslash \{0\}.
$$

Comment: Hi @Three aggies , apologies for responding late. After your answer this I will restart the bounty and award it to your answer. Just to clarify, here my initial form is not quite a group of lie symetries as per the definition. Regardless, what ends up happening in this particular case is that the lie symmetry which corresponds to the generator can actually be written as in the initial set up, with $c=e^{\epsilon}$. Is this right? Also is there some sort of general procedure to get a lie symmetry of a specific form? Perhaps doing as above is the general way?

Comment: You don't have to restart the bounty. I didn't do anything for this question. You wrote all the correct things, but you still don't feel convinced. I am not too sure where the doubt was exactly. But to repeat, your Lie point symmetry is the symmetry of the system, as long as you let $c=e^\epsilon$. Eventually, the group is $({\mathbb R}_+, \cdot)$, the positive real numbers under multiplication.

Comment: In general, I think people find the symmetry vector fields first, then integrate to get the group. In general, the symmetry group is rather big, and it can be infinite dimensional. A one-parameter group is just a subgroup in there. I am not too big a fan of such theories, but there is the book "Applications of Lie groups to Differential Equations" by P. Olver, and you can see if this is something you want to pursue further.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have restarted the bounty and I will be awarding it as soon as the timeframe allows

Comment: Thank you. It is very nice of you!